# pandoc template $if$ statement for fenced code snippets in markdown

Tags: templates, code, pandoc, markdown, code-snippets

I am wondering if it is possible to do in a latex.template for Pandoc:

```latex
\begin{document}

$if(fencedcode)$
\begin{lstlisting}
$content within fenced code$
\end{lstlisting}
$endif$

\end{document}
```

where `$content within fenced code$` would be marked as follows in the markdown file (as specified in the [Pandoc User’s Guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_code_attributes):

````markdown
```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
```
````

Maybe to better explain my question, I would like to avoid having to write within my markdown file something like that:

```markdown
#Introduction
Content…

\begin{lstlisting}{bash}

    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"

\end{lstlisting}

more content…
```

Thus keeping the markdown file cleaner and simpler to read with less `raw latex` inside, like so:

````markdown
#Introduction
Content…

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
```

more content…
````

### Edit

the `\begin{lstlisting}…\end{lstlisting}` latex command is actually a personalized listing command within a `class.cls` file. So what I’m trying to achieve is that when the `source.md` file is processed with pandoc and the relevant template, when Pandoc sees the `fenced code block` it processes it not with regular `\begin{listings}` but with the personalized command `\begin{TMcode}…\end{TMcode}`, that is defined in the `class.cls` below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{TMarticle}
\LoadClass{article} % we use a standard article as a base-class

\RequirePackage{listings} % for our code listings
\RequirePackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

% color definitions
\definecolor{TMgreen}{RGB}{14, 191, 48}
\definecolor{TMorange}{RGB}{243, 126, 25}
\definecolor{TMred}{RGB}{230, 6, 85}
\definecolor{TMcodeBackground}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\definecolor{TMcodeFrame}{RGB}{109, 108, 109}
\definecolor{TMtableHead}{RGB}{230, 6, 85}
\definecolor{TMtableRowTwo}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
\definecolor{TMtableRowOne}{RGB}{240, 240, 240}
\definecolor{TMemphasis}{RGB}{165, 32, 23}
\definecolor{TMwarning}{RGB}{250, 175, 52}
\definecolor{TMcritical}{RGB}{229, 0, 72}
\definecolor{TMnormal}{RGB}{54, 160, 220}
\definecolor{TMbulletinBackground}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}
\definecolor{TMtheorem}{RGB}{14, 191, 48}

% font settings
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[BoldFont=Source Code Pro]
\setmainfont{Lato Light}[
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]
\setsansfont{Lato Light}[
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{Lato Light}[
    Numbers=OldStyle,
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]

% Font for chapter number
\newfontfamily{\upperNumber}{Lato Light}[
    BoldFont=Lato Regular,
    ItalicFont=Lato Light Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Lato Italic
]

% we now start creating the TM-styled code listing environments
% the lstlisting environment is wrapped in an MD-frame
% first of all we need to define the mdframestyle that
% takes care of the background and the left bar

\mdfdefinestyle{TMstyleCode}{
            skipabove=4mm,
            skipbelow=0mm,
            %remove borders
            rightline=false,
            topline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=1mm,
            %margins
            innertopmargin=2mm,
            innerleftmargin=0mm,
            innerbottommargin=0mm,
            innerrightmargin=10pt,
            linecolor=TMcodeFrame,
            backgroundcolor=TMcodeBackground
}

\lstdefinestyle{TMstyle}{
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{TMgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{TMorange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{TMred},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

% need to use inner commands to avoid the verbatim nature
% of listing environments!

\lstnewenvironment{TMcode}[3]
{
    \lstset{style=TMstyle, language=#1, caption=#2}
    \mdfsetup{style=TMstyleCode}
    \mdframed
    \hspace*{3mm}
    \minipage{0.75cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/code2.png}
    \endminipage
    \hspace*{1mm}
    \minipage{\textwidth-1.05cm}
        {\sffamily\Large #3}
    \endminipage
    \vspace*{-2mm}
}
{
    \endmdframed
}

% We now want to create the bulletin-environments
% we first define two new mdenvironments, one for the header and one for
% the content
\newmdenv[
        skipabove=4mm,
        skipbelow=1mm,
        innertopmargin=1mm,
        innerbottommargin=1mm,
        innerleftmargin=0mm,
        innerrightmargin=0pt,
        rightline=false,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        linewidth=1mm,
        frametitlefont={\sffamily\bfseries},
        backgroundcolor=TMbulletinBackground]{TMbulletinBase}
\newmdenv[default, linewidth=0pt, backgroundcolor=TMbulletinBackground]{TMbulletinContent}

% we then define three styles, one for each type
\mdfdefinestyle{normal}{linecolor=TMnormal}
\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{linecolor=TMwarning}
\mdfdefinestyle{critical}{linecolor=TMcritical}

% we then define some auxilliary commands
\newcommand{\@TMbulletinTitleContent}[2]
{
    \hspace*{2mm}\begin{minipage}{0.75cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
    \end{minipage}\hspace*{1mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-1.05cm}
            #2
    \end{minipage}
}

% and finally the main environment
% takes type (warning/normal/critical) as first argument
% takes bulletin title as second argument
\newenvironment{TMbulletin}[2]{
    \begin{TMbulletinBase}[style=#1, frametitle=\@TMbulletinTitleContent{images/#1.png}{#2}]
    \vspace*{1mm}
    \begin{TMbulletinContent}
}
{
    \end{TMbulletinContent}
    \end{TMbulletinBase}
}

% we now define the mdtable styles
\newcommand{\tableCaption}{}
\mdfdefinestyle{TMstyleTable}{
            skipabove=4mm,
            skipbelow=0mm,
            %remove borders
            rightline=false,
            topline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=1mm,
            %margins
            innertopmargin=0mm,
            innerleftmargin=0mm,
            innerbottommargin=0mm,
            innerrightmargin=0pt,
            backgroundcolor=TMcodeBackground,
            linecolor=TMtableHead,
}
\everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm white]{}}
\tabulinesep=^3mm_2mm
\taburowcolors[2] 2{TMtableRowOne .. TMtableRowTwo}
\newenvironment{TMtable}[3]
{
    \renewcommand{\tableCaption}{#3}
    \begin{table}[#2]
    \begin{mdframed}[style=TMstyleTable]
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth{#1}
        \rowfont{\bfseries\sffamily\leavevmode\color{white}}
        \rowcolor{TMtableHead!}
}
{
    \end{tabu}
    \end{mdframed}
    \caption{\tableCaption}
    \end{table}
}

% theorem styles
\declaretheoremstyle[
    postheadspace=\newline,
    headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    mdframed={
            skipabove=4mm,
            skipbelow=0mm,
            rightline=false,
            topline=false,
            bottomline=false,
            linewidth=1mm,
            linecolor=TMtheorem,
            backgroundcolor=TMcodeBackground,
    }
]{TMtheoremStyle}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, within=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, sibling=theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, sibling=theorem]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=TMtheoremStyle, sibling=theorem]{proposition}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and don't link to off-site code. Questions should be self-contained

Comment: I can’t really give you a MWE since I don’t know how to make it **work**. It’s not a question about something that does not work, it’s a question about something to be created, which I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

According to your edit and comments, it seems that the question you are *actually* asking is how to change the commands used by pandoc's latex writer. The most transparent and straight forward way to do this, is to write a Lua filter that changes the way how of code blocks are generated.

The first step is to figure out, how code blocks are internally represented in pandoc's AST. You can see what's going on, by converting your example to `native` with `pandoc --to native source.md`, where `source.md` contains

````
```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
```
````

The output shows

```
[ CodeBlock
    ( "" , [ "bash" ] , [] )
    "    #!/bin/bash\n    echo \"hello world\""
]
```

Now, the second step is to write a [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) (let's call it `TMcode.lua`) for the `CodeBlock` that returns `\begin{TMcode} . . . \end{TMcode}` instead of `\begin{lstlisting} . . . \end{lstlisting}`.

```
function CodeBlock(block)
  if FORMAT == "beamer" or FORMAT == "latex" then
    local raw_code = string.format(
      "\\begin{TMcode}%s\n%s\n\\end{TMcode}",
      block.classes[1] and "[language=" .. block.classes[1] .. "]" or "",
      block.text
    )
    return pandoc.RawBlock("latex", raw_code)
  end
end
```

Finally, you can call `pandoc --lua-filter=TMcode.lua --to latex source.md` and get

```
\begin{TMcode}[language=bash]
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
\end{TMcode}
```

---

Maybe I don't understand your question. The syntax for code blocks in pandoc is:

````
```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
```
````

I.e. the code block ends with ticks not dots.

If you want to use a lstlisting environment, you have to call pandoc with the option `--listings`.

This will generate the following code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
\end{lstlisting}
```

Cf. https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_code_attributes

Comment: I thought you can use `...` at the end of code blocks as well https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute. But in any case, it’s fine, I used it with back tilts as well. The question is to call the listing environment but not within the `.md` file, rather with the template. i.e., you would still write the fenced code block in `source.md` and the template would recognize and call a listing environment with an `$if$` statement.

Comment: I am confused. If you are writing a template for latex, you have to use latex. In the markdown source, you can use markdown. Maybe you want to elaborate a bit what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: That’s precisely what I’m trying to achieve: I do not want to write latex code in the `source.md` file, I want to only write Markdown in the markdown file. Therefore, I want to make a pandoc template with an `$if$` statement so that when pandoc sees a `fenced code block` it executes a personalized `\begin{lstlisting} … \end{lstlisting}` command. That’s what might be unclear, actually; I’ll edit the question.

Comment: I am still confused: `source.md` is a markdown file, here you can write markdown. The template file `whatever.latex`, which is used to generate the output (and which loads the `document class`), hast to be written in latex + commands using the `$`-syntax, which will be replaced by pandoc.

Comment: In `source.md` with Pandoc, you can also write latex code. The idea of Pandoc markdown though, is to avoid using latex code in `source.md` by using the `whatever.latex` template (which is the default settings of Pandoc; it uses the `--template=default.latex` as default settings). Now my idea is to push that a bit further and have `$if$` statement in the `whatever.template` so that when I use fenced code blocks in `source.md` instead of calling whatever Pandoc usually calls, it calls my custom latex `\begin{lstlisting}…\end{lstlisting}`.

Comment: You could use a lua filter to replace `lstlisting` with `TMcode`. See update